# php refresh on 2nd page refresh

Tags: php, refresh

i have this function that gives me an output of a number. (the number is my total amount of downloads from my iphone themes.)
because the code has to make so many requests, it loads the page very slowly.
what would be the best way for me to go about the code loading into a variable and than calling it on the second page refresh. so it dosnt take so long to load?

or any other method will do. i just want it to not take so long to load!

also this isnt on my server so i cant use $.ajax

```
<?php
function all_downloads() { 
 $allThemes = array( 
  'com.modmyi.batterytheme',
  'com.modmyi.connectiontheme',
  'com.modmyi.icontheme',
  'com.modmyi.percenttheme',
  'com.modmyi.statusnotifiertheme',
  'com.modmyi.cnote',
  'com.modmyi.iaccescnotekb',
  'com.modmyi.cnotelite',
  'com.modmyi.multibrowsericon',
  'com.modmyi.changeappstoreiconwithinstallous'
 );
 $total = 0;
 foreach($allThemes as $com_modmyi){
  $theme = file_get_contents( "http://modmyi.com/cstats/index.php?package=".$com_modmyi.'&output=number');
  $theme = str_replace(",","", $theme);
  $almost_done += $theme;
  $rock_your_phone = 301; //From c-note and Multi Lock Screen Theme on Rock Your Phone
  $total = ($almost_done + $rock_your_phone);
 }
 echo number_format($total);
}
?>
```

Comment: Which part takes so long to load? I assume it's the `file_get_contents()`, which means you probably have to look into your cstats script and not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the function with [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp) !

Th basic idea of using ajax is to to help make web applications function more like desktop applications

most actions that an end-user takes in his or her browser send a request back to the web server. The server then processes that request, perhaps sends out further requests, and eventually responds with whatever the user requested. <--**whats your problem is ** **(slow !)**

with AJAX you can call a PHP function with out reloading a page

please go though this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp) which is really simple

Comment: im still a little new to javascript. could you show me an example please.

i tried .ajax but found out since the url's are not on my server i couldnt use it. but your saying just call my completed function with ajax?